# Swift protocol conformance issue with sub type of protocol

Tags: swift

```swift
internal protocol Reducer {
        associatedtype S : BaseState
        associatedtype A : BaseAction
        
        func reduce(state: S, action: A) -> S
    }
    
    internal class ReducerImpl : Reducer {
        func reduce(state: MainState, action: MainAction) -> MainState { //<-- Error because MainAction is a protocol not a concrete one.
            return state
        }
    }
    
    internal class MainState : BaseState {}
    internal protocol MainAction : BaseAction {}
    
    internal protocol BaseState {}
    internal protocol BaseAction {}
```

If I change `MainAction` from protocol to class, the compile error disappears.

I've searching many articles to understand of this error but failed.

Do I have to pass a *concrete* parameter(eg. enum, class, struct) in `reduce(...)` function?

I want to make `ReducerImpl` can take various action type that conform MainAction.

Is there anyone who can give me explain about that error and why the Swift adopt this kind of rule.

Comment: This feels like a very elaborate way to express a simple function. Can you give an example of the calling code that relies on this protocol? The fact that you need "Base..." protocols suggests your trying to reinvent class-inheritance with protocols (also the fact that you call it a "subtype" which is not a good way to think about protocols that require other protocols). Start with the calling code and the algorithms that you're trying to implement, and the protocols will follow. A protocol is not an abstract class. It is a set of requirements with semantics, allowing you to write algorithms.

Comment: The more I look at this, the only possible (pure, non-crashing) implementation of this protocol is ReducerImpl. It is literally impossible to make use of the `action` parameter. I know you've simplified things for the question, but there comes a point when you've removed the point of the question. It is impossible to use this protocol for a useful purpose, which suggests you've removed the part that will provide the answer.

Comment: What do you need `BaseState` and `BaseState`? I assume the reducers can operate on a variety of data types, thus constraining all of them to a common protocol for consuming it in the reducer doesn't seem feasible. Drop the two `Base` protocols, they cause more problem than they solve.

Answer (score 2):

`associatedtype` has to be concrete, ie. a *type* and not a *protocol*.

What you can do is to create a narrower protocol with a generic function that accepts a `MainAction` parameter:

```
internal protocol MainReducer {
    associatedtype State
    func reduce<Action>(state: State, action: Action) -> State where Action: MainAction
}

internal class ReducerImpl: MainReducer {
    func reduce<Action>(state: MainState, action: Action) -> MainState where Action: MainAction {
        return state
    }
}
```